# Doctrine2 - Single Table Inheritance

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, single-table-inheritance, autoloader

I'm trying to apply this [tutorial](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) to my project, but I don't get it working. Everytime I try to update my schema i get an error:
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Rueckgrat\App\Models\ProjectSetting in.....

I have 2 files. The first one is ProjectSetting.php

```
namespace Rueckgrat\App\Models;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="project_setting")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="is_production", type="integer")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"0" = "ProjectCalculation", "1" = "ProjectSetting"})
 */
class ProjectSetting
{
// More code here
}
```

The second one is ProjectCalculation.php

```
namespace Rueckgrat\App\Models;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ProjectCalculation extends \Rueckgrat\App\Models\ProjectSetting
{      
....
}
```

Any help or hint appreciated.

**Update:**

Full error message:
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Rueckgrat\App\Models\ProjectSetting in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Rueckgrat/app/models/ProjectSetting.php on line 17

I just tried the example from the Doctrine documentation, just splited in two entity files and it is not working. Then i copied the ProjectCalculation class in the file of ProjectSetting and it is working.

**Update 2:**

I can't update my Schema, but it is saving the correct discriminator to the project_setting table, when i save an ProjectCalculation Entity.

Comment: The error message is perhaps very important, please do not truncate it.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Rueckgrat\App\Models\ProjectSetting in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Rueckgrat/app/models/ProjectSetting.php on line 17

Comment: can you find `class ProjectSetting` in any other file? The second option in your DiscriminatorMap declaration looks suspicious.

Comment: no, there is no double declaration of the ProjectSetting Class. What do you mean with suspicious? Its like in the documentation, or?!

Comment: My bad, I thought there should be no option for the mother class, but obviously, you can do that.

Comment: Are you sure the ProjectCalculation class definition is correct: class ProjectCalculation extends \Rueckgrat\App\Models\ProjectSetting. Shouldn't it simply be class ProjectCalculation extends ProjectSetting. Of course previus to this you should type use \Rueckgrat\App\Models\ProjectSetting;

Comment: it doesn't matter, how you declare the class. and i get the same error, when i do it like you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be the problem with PHP accelerator on your machine. Please turn off APC or XCache (whatever you have there), restart PHP/Apache and try again.

Comment: thanks i will try that, but i found out that the cli script caused much trouble. if i generate my entities, proxies and database via php it is working. only when i do it via CLI i get those errors.